# How to make translate3d element respect z-index in Mobile Safari?

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari, translate3d

I found a wired issue in Mobile Safari as demo http://mocheng.github.com/demo/translate3d.html

There is one page **translate3d_iframe.html** inside **translate.html** as iframe. Elements in **translate3d_iframe.html** has style **-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)** to force 3d acceleration.

The interesting result is that the 3D-ed element would always displayed on top of other elements event it has lower z-index.

What is more interesting: the 3D-ed element is just displayed to be on top of other elements. You can still tap on the menu item "hidden by" 3D-ed element (alert message is shown on tap).

This can only be reproduced in Mobile Safari.

Is there anyway to workaround it? I just felt that web developers have to know how iOS browser works to attack such type of issues.

Comment: It's a little upsetting not to see a solution here yet...keep me posted if you find one!

Comment: Seems there is no solution. So, the key is "Never use iframe in mobile web for ever".

Comment: Not just iframes - we have divs positioned with translate3d (jQuery isotope plugin) and our menu divs et al appear behind them in mobile-web kit based browsers

Comment: DIV with translate3d doesn't respect z-index. This is a known issue.

Comment: Hi @MorganCheng -- did you ever find your answer here?  I'm running into the same issue, but with respect to different 3d-ed elements... and each other!